# Parse and load GPX into database?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, gpx

Having a PostgreSQL database, with the following tables:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trips CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips (
  trip_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  start_location bigint NULL,  -- location id
  end_location bigint NULL,   -- location id

  start_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  end_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  bounds geography(POLYGON, 4326) NOT NULL, 
  points geography(LINESTRING, 4326) NOT NULL,
  timestamps TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE[] NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips_transportation_modes (
  mode_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  trip_id SERIAL REFERENCES trips(trip_id) NOT NULL,
  label TEXT NOT NULL,
  start_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  end_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  start_index INTEGER NOT NULL,
  end_index INTEGER NOT NULL,
  bounds GEOGRAPHY(POLYGON, 4326) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations (
  label TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  centroid GEOGRAPHY(POINTZ, 4326) NOT NULL,
  point_cluster geography(MULTIPOINT, 4326) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stays (
  stay_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  trip_id SERIAL REFERENCES trips(trip_id),
  location_label TEXT REFERENCES locations(label),
  start_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  end_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

I am connected to the database and will be making some queries using Flask (Python). This application is supposed to encode the query results in JSON/GeoJSON, to be sent to my front-end.

The problem here is to populate this database. I need to load a folder containing multiple GPX files, parse them and fill these tables with the information I got from the GPX's. Is this attainable with python?

Basically the idea is to get the list of GPX files and parse each one.

Out of the scope of this question, in the future I will convert the parsed results to the formats specified by the tables, and then insert the data in the database using the psycopg library (that I'm already using to connect to the database).

Is there already a good approach to this problem? Or do I need to start it from scratch?

Comment: Search GIS.se for GPX and spatialite, think you'll find some similar solutions.

Comment: @Simbamangu I am not looking for spatialite. PostGIS only

Comment: yes you should be able to do this-i have done something similar to what you are describing but I was parsing through csvs with lat long values and inserting them into Postgres using the pyscopg library.

Comment: @ziggy can you share the way you have done it?

Comment: yes i will post in a few minutes

Comment: This question is too broad as it stands - you need to (1) read GPX files and (2) interpret the spatial data to populate your current tables. It would be best if you edit your question to focus on one part of the question, showing the approaches you've tried already and where you are stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo This is really getting into my nerves. What have I done wrong this time for a question of mine to be on hold again? I have explained all there is that I know/have tried.

Comment: I can only speak for my own close vote. You are asking for an approach rather than asking a focussed question. Looking at your sentence that starts "Basically" there seem to be 3-4 hurdles you know you need to overcome. Just ask about the first place you are stuck not all the places you may get stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo I understand. But those hurdles are part of a line of thought...

Comment: @PolyGeo Edited nonetheless. See if you can take it from hold please.

Comment: You still seem to be asking for a review of your approach instead of asking a single focussed question about one step, what you tried and where you are stuck. As it stands you could ask your question in the GIS Chat Room but I think focussed Q&A is the way to overcome hurdles a hurdle at a time.

Comment: Please do not underestimate the help that taking the [Tour], which leads into http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question, can provide.  These are designed to help those new to this site and focussed Q&A to understand that this is not the same as posting on a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially my project was to loop through 7 folders: 1-7 representing days and in each folder there were thousands of csvs containing pickup and dropoff locations. You will have to mess around with your path names. I also never parsed GPX files, I am not sure how different that is from reading csvs. But this script should give you a decent understanding of what you are trying to accomplish

```
import os
import sys
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='rz' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='bla'") #connecting to DB
cur = conn.cursor()  #setting up connection cursor
cur.execute('''drop table routepoints''')
#setting up route points table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE routepoints
            (pid serial primary key,
             driver_id INT,
             day_of_week  varchar,
             pickup_lng float,
             pickup_lat float,
             dropoff_lng float,
             dropoff_lat float,
             pickup_geom geometry,
             dropoff_geom geometry);''')
conn.commit()
path = 'C:\\' #storing path in variable-your going to have mess around with your path
folderday = 1                                                   
for mainfolder in os.listdir('C:\\Users'):   #path folders..
    for subfolders in os.listdir(path+str(folderday)):  #path folders..
        driver_id2 = subfolders.replace(".csv", "")    
        driver_id = int(driver_id2)                    
        day_of_week = folderday
        if day_of_week == 1: day_of_week = 'Sunday'    
        elif day_of_week == 2: day_of_week = 'Monday'
        elif day_of_week == 3: day_of_week = 'Tuesday'
        elif day_of_week == 4: day_of_week = 'Wednesday'
        elif day_of_week == 5: day_of_week = 'Thursday'
        elif day_of_week == 6: day_of_week = 'Friday'
        elif day_of_week == 7: day_of_week = 'Saturday'
        print day_of_week, driver_id
        csvs = open(path+str(folderday)+'\\'+subfolders) #opening csvs
        for info in csvs:
            coords = info.split()                        #splitting coords based on whitespace
            if len(coords) < 4:
                print path+str(folderday)+'\\'+subfolders
                sys.exit()
            pickup_lng = float(coords[0])  #storing coords...
            pickup_lat = float(coords[1])
            dropoff_lng = float(coords[2])
            dropoff_lat = float(coords[3])
            #insert statement to routepoints table
            cur.execute('''insert into routepoints (driver_id, day_of_week, pickup_lng, pickup_lat, dropoff_lng,
             dropoff_lat, pickup_geom, dropoff_geom)
             values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4269),
              ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4269))''', (driver_id, day_of_week, pickup_lng, pickup_lat, dropoff_lng,
                                                           dropoff_lat, pickup_lng, pickup_lat, dropoff_lng,
                                                           dropoff_lat, ))
            conn.commit()
    folderday+=1
```

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're trying to accomplish here, and it seems to be the general idea. But I think that for GPX files it may be a tad different because of its specificities. I was hoping someone would have already cracked this problem, or if there is any plugin or library available.

Comment: did you check this out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gpxpy

Comment: or try using element tree to parse through the GPX files-once you extract the data it should be relatively the same

Comment: https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy

Comment: I didn't knew about that gpxpy library. I'm going to investigate it. But it seems I have to do the insertion on the DB myself